# dotnet core paypal GetAccessToken returns 401 for live, but works on sandbox

Tags: asp.net-core, paypal

trying to go live with paypal on a asp.net core website, but I'm unable to get an access token, I keep getting  PayPal.HttpException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

here's the problematic code section:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> configurationMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        configurationMap.Add("clientId", _options.PayPalClientId);
        configurationMap.Add("clientSecret", _options.PayPalClientSecret);
        configurationMap.Add("mode", _options.PayPalMode);

        _logger.Info($"paypal data: mode={_options.PayPalMode}, client id={_options.PayPalClientId}");
        var accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(_options.PayPalClientId, _options.PayPalClientSecret, configurationMap).GetAccessToken();
        var apiContext = new APIContext(accessToken) { Config = configurationMap };
```

the nuget packages I use are:

```
<PackageReference Include="PayPal" Version="2.0.0-rc2"/>
<PackageReference Include="PayPalCore" Version="1.0.0"/>
```

looking at log to make sure the mode=live and the clientId is the the live one (so I'm sure the secret was also loaded correctly).

this code works fine on my workstation and on my dev server (running IIS & kestrel), using the sandbox clientId/secret.
however, on the production server in AWS, I get this error.
running postman on the AWS windows server to make sure it can communicate with paypal's api works, I can get the accesstoken, so it's not a firewall issue.

any other leads?

Answer (score 3):

to anyone having the same issue, or wondering which paypal sdk to use for a dotnet core app, this did the trick:

```
<PackageReference Include="PayPal.SDK.NETCore" Version="1.9.1.2" />
```